# javascript remove div onclick

Tags: javascript, html

with pure javascript, I need to remove a `li` on click the `span`.

- By clicking `remove` I want to remove its div.

```js
Object.prototype.remove = function(){
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};

var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var button = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', remove, false);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>List item one<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item two<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item three<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item four<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item five<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item six<span> remove</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want remove which div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't pollute `Object`. You don't need this function in every object. Create an separate function and use `remove()`, not `removeChild()`.

**The ChildNode.remove() method removes the object from the tree it belongs to.**

But remove doesn't work in every browser. It is a new function. So I suggest you two solutions.

With `remove()`

```js
var remove = function(){
    this.parentNode.remove();
};

var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var button = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', remove, false);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>List item one<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item two<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item three<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item four<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item five<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item six<span> remove</span></li>
</ul>
```

With `removeChild()`.

**Why 2 parentNodes?**

Because the first is the `<span>`, but you need `li`

```js
function remove() {
  this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}

var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var button = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', remove, false);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item one<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item two<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item three<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item four<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item five<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item six<span> remove</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think most people aren't aware of `remove()` which is better and are used to `removeChild()`.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant response and effect!

Answer (score 1):

Try following solution.

```js
Object.prototype.remove = function(){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
};

var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var button = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', remove, false);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>List item one<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item two<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item three<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item four<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item five<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item six<span> remove</span></li>
</ul>
```

It would be better to just define a simple function instead of changing the `object` prototype, as @Satpal suggested.

```js
function remove() {
  this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}

var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var button = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', remove, false);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item one<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item two<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item three<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item four<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item five<span> remove</span></li>
  <li>List item six<span> remove</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you need to pollute `Object`? Suggest OP to define a simple function

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the < li > element that contains the "remove" option?
If so, that's how to do it.

```js
Object.prototype.remove = function(){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
};

var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var button = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', remove, false);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>List item one<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item two<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item three<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item four<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item five<span> remove</span></li>
    <li>List item six<span> remove</span></li>
</ul>
```